# order of unpacking *args in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

I wonder why variable `last`is `5`
when i do

```
first, *rest, last = 1,2,3,4,5
```

I thought assignment goes from left to right, thus 
`*rest` will be `[2,3,4,5]`, but it actualy is `[2,3,4]`
And I thought that last will be empty, or this code will cause error, but suprisingly it works, but I dont understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a valid syntax only in Python 3, is called "extended unpacking" and it is defined in PEP 3132 - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's unpacking feature.

`first` and `last` are just variables, when `*rest` are arguments, so they get everything between `first` and `last` value in tuple (1,2,3,4,5).

If you want to have you wrote:

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

then just use:

```
first, *args = 1,2,3,4,5
# first --> 1
# args --> [2,3,4,5]
```